# How to create the module default instance during the module installation in moodle?

Tags: moodle

In game modules of moodle site , I want to add the feature for users to have the option to try the game first in case they don't wanna create yet. 
So, I need to create the default game instances during the game module plugin installation  to play the demo game.

Any body can help me how to create modules instance during the module installation and in which tables I need to insert the default data record?
I use mdl_course_modules table and my module table mdl_game and give course ID 1 but it doesn't enough and facing the invalid course module error in require_login() function
when I play the demo game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add instances during install, create /local/yourplugin/db/install.php

with

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

function xmldb_local_yourplugin_install() {
    // Create your instances here.
}
```

Note that this is for install only, if the plugin is already installed then you need to use update.php

UPDATE: update.php is slightly different, you will need to check and update the version too

```
function  xmldb_local_yourplugin_upgrade($oldversion) {

    if ($oldversion < yyyyddmmxx) {

        // Add your instances here.


        // Plugin savepoint reached.
        upgrade_plugin_savepoint(true, yyyyddmmxx, 'local', 'yourplugin');
    }
```

Comment: If I use update.php, the function name is like that?
function xmldb_local_yourplugin_update() {
    // Create your instances here.
}